# How to set html and body tags height correctly to fill all available space

Tags: html, css, height, screen

I tried all combinations of min-height and height values, but nothing worked good.

Here is JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qjegr98o/

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.lot-of-content {
  height: 2000px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="full-height">
  <div class="lot-of-content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please, try to scroll down in the result frame and you will see, that the yellow background does not fill all space.

Goal is to make this yellow background fill all available space even when you scroll down, but also fill whole screen when the content is small (for example just one row).

How to achieve that? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: min-height to the full-height

Comment: It is not working to add just min-height. Can you please update the fiddle to show your solution?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zwfpn2t6/

Comment: In your solution, html element has height equal only to the screen height and not all the content. You can check that in developer tools. That causes problems in my application and it is a reason for this question here.

Comment: apply min-height on it then .. the trick is min-height instead of height

Comment: Thank you very much for response. But then it does not work for small content. If you remove height: 2000px; rule of .lot-of-content class, you will see that issue. I have a dynamic content, so I need to handle both cases - 100px of content, but also 2000px of content.

Comment: use min-height:100vh

Comment: But if body element has min-height: 100vh, then if you set content height to 100%, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: not body, only the full-height div .. remove everything else from body/html